# Opening file only once before writing to it in an async loop using boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Based on one of the previous questions I posted, I have implemented a separate async thread that dumps the contents of a container every 10 seconds using the steady_timer from the boost::asio library. It looks as follows:

```
m_outfile.open("numbers.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
            
for (auto val : number_container) {
                m_outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val), sizeof(int));

                if (m_outfile.bad()) {
                    throw std::runtime_error("Error in writing to numbers.bin");
                }
            }

            m_timer.expires_at(m_timer.expiry() + boost::asio::chrono::seconds(NUM_SECONDS_DUMP));
            m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Data_dump::dump, this));
```

This is just part of the code but you can see that I open a file, loop through a container and write the contents into the file.
The problem here is with the very first line - it should only be used once or else the code crashes after 10 seconds when I enter this code again. I have put a while loop around the first line that only runs once like so:

```
            while (testing == 0) {
                m_outfile.open("numbers.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
                testing++;
            }
```

This works fine as testing is a global variable, but  I am not sure about declaring a global variable and having to check this while loop all the time even though it will never enter it. Just looking for a better solution to this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a class member. It's not global, each object instance will have its own copy.

Because it's also not local to the function, it will stay around across member function calls on the same object.

I'd argue that you don't need a flag, because you can ask the stream whether it was already open:

```
if (!m_outfile.is_open())
    m_outfile.open(filename, std::ios::binary);
```

Since you want exceptions on error, consider enabling them on the file stream:

```
m_outfile.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
```

Consider using the actual size of `val`, instead of duplicating the assumed type (`int`).

```
for (auto val : number_container) {
    m_outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val),
                    sizeof(val));
}
```

(aside: If `number_container` is contiguous, you can more efficiently write that as:

```
auto span = as_bytes(std::span(number_container));
m_outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(span.data()), span.size());
```

/aside)

Here's a live demo [On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53ce5bdc31218c79)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
static constexpr auto DUMP_INTERVAL = 1s;

struct Data_dump {
    Data_dump() { //
        m_outfile.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    }

    void foo() {
        try {
            if (!m_outfile.is_open())
                m_outfile.open(m_filename, std::ios::binary);

            //for (auto val : number_container) {
                //m_outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val),
                                //sizeof(val));
            //}
            auto span = as_bytes(std::span(number_container));
            m_outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(span.data()), span.size());
            m_outfile.flush();

            m_timer.expires_at(m_timer.expiry() + DUMP_INTERVAL);
            m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Data_dump::dump, this, boost::placeholders::_1));
            std::cerr << "Expiry: " << (m_timer.expiry() - std::chrono::steady_clock::now())/1ms << "ms\n";
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Error in writing to " + m_filename);
        }
    }

    void run() {
        ioc.run_for(10s); // for COLIRU
    }

private:
    void dump(boost::system::error_code ec) {
        // don't use rand in production code!
        std::cerr << "Dump (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        generate(begin(number_container), end(number_container), std::rand);

        foo();
    }

    std::string const         m_filename = "numbers.bin";
    boost::asio::io_context   ioc;
    boost::asio::steady_timer m_timer{ioc, 1s};
    std::ofstream             m_outfile;
    std::vector<int>          number_container{1, 2, 3};
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    Data_dump dd;

    dd.foo();
    dd.run();

}
```

Showing the timings:

[image]

### BONUS

In your case, it looks like you might not actually need async IO (you're not using it in the code shown), so maybe just write it like:

```
void foo(std::string const& filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    ofs.open(filename, std::ios::binary);

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto now = start; now <= start + 10s; now += DUMP_INTERVAL) {
        /*
         *for (auto val : data)
         *    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
         */

        auto span = as_bytes(std::span(data));
        ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(span.data()), span.size());
        ofs.flush();

        std::this_thread::sleep_until(now + 1s);
    }
}
```

Now, perhaps add a thread to update the number container (be sure to add synchronization e.g. using a lock, or atomic exchange etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and very detailed answer :) Can't believe I did not just check if the file is open lol so silly of me. Thank you for showing me all these different ways I can optimize my code, first time touching network and file stuff so good to know the optimal ways.
I do actually need to use boost and async as its what I am being tested on, so even if its not the best practice, just need to show I know how to use it!

Comment: Hey guys bac with a bit of a problem, if you look at my code I posted here, it worked fine with a **vector** number container. I just changed from **std::vector** to **std::set** and now the binary file is empty :( any advice in a bit of a panic

Comment: It should just work. Why don't you show the code? Your're obviously doing something wrong. Compare: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d9a337f51b13ca) and [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d9a337f51b13ca)